# Is there some type of json mashup?

Tags: json

I have a number of jsons and I want to manually select some parts of it to create a new Z json one. Is there any software that do that or I have to program that?

Example:

X is a temperature JSON:

```
{
    "temperature" : 20,
    "standard" : "Celsius"
}
```

Y is a wind JSON:

```
{
    "windSpeed": 12,
    "unit" : "Knot"
}
```

I want a Z json that would be a selection of the X + Y, for instance I want only the speed and temperature:

```
{
    "temperature" : 20,
    "windSpeed" : 12
}
```

My question is, is given a static X and Y is there a way to build Z without manually taking out the fields of X and Y? I mean is there a gui or technique that allows me to produce a JSON from other JSONS?

Comment: Erm, what?  What do you mean by "X json" and "new Y json"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to manually program it to parse the JSON and output a new one.  Should be pretty easy, though, to be honest.  Just select based on a keyword and then pass it into the new JSON object.